# Android Google Maps Polyline not showing on Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-roads-api

I have made a class that have a method and a locaton listener. The locationListener will be executed every 2 seconds , gets the lat longs and will pass it to the Async Task. The Async Task class will pass the lat longs to Google Road Api to get snapped lat longs and will pass the lat longs to postExecute()

The PostExecute() should draw the polylines But it does not..

Please See the below code.:

MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.akshay.roadsapi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    final String URL = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=";
    final String KEY = "API KEY HERE";
    int i = 0;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, LatLng> latLng1 = null;
    Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(MapsActivity.this, latLng, URL, KEY, activity, mMap);

                    backgroundTask.execute();


                /*mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1));*/
            }


            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

BackgroundTask.java

```
package com.example.akshay.roadsapi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 9/8/2015.
 */
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LatLng> {
    Context CONTEXT;
    LatLng LATLNGS;
    String URL;
    String KEY;
    Double LAT = null;
    Double LONG = null;
    GoogleMap map;
    Activity ACTIVITY;
    myInt myInt = null;
    int flag = 0;
    LatLng prev;
    LatLng latlng;

    public BackgroundTask(Context context, LatLng LATLNGS, String URL, String KEY, Activity ACTIVITY, GoogleMap map) {
        this.CONTEXT = context;
        this.LATLNGS = LATLNGS;
        this.URL = URL;
        this.KEY = KEY;
        this.ACTIVITY = ACTIVITY;
        this.map = map;

    }


    @Override
    protected LatLng doInBackground(Void... params) {


        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        InputStream inputStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder strin = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            get.setURI(new URI(URL + LATLNGS.latitude + "," + LATLNGS.longitude + "&interpolate=false&key=" + KEY));
            response = client.execute(get);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStreamReader = entity.getContent();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreamReader));
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                strin.append(line + "\n");
            }

            Log.e("============", strin.toString());

            JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(strin.toString());
            JSONArray array = ob.getJSONArray("snappedPoints");
            for (int i = 0; i <= array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location");
                LAT = object.getDouble("latitude");
                LONG = object.getDouble("longitude");

            }

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        latlng= new LatLng(LAT, LONG);
        return latlng;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
        super.onPostExecute(latLng);
       /* MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
        map.addMarker(markerOptions);*/




        if (flag == 0) {
            prev = latLng;
            flag = 1;
        }
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18);
       /* Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));*/


        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.add(prev, latLng).color(Color.BLUE).width(50).visible(true);
        map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);




        prev = latLng;


        latLng = null;

    }
}
```

I am getting the Json Array From GOOGLE API and getting the lats long values successfully but polyline is not Drawn..
Please Help

Thanks